# exception when passing array in function to scanf

Tags: c, function, parameters

I do not understand why I am receiving this exception every time I attempt to enter a value for name.

This is the exception I get, Exception thrown at 0x0F59B211 (ucrtbased.dll) in Program3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFCC.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

I am new to c so please explain thoroughly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int askUser(char name[5][16],float hourlyRate[5],float hoursWorked[5])
{
    int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    printf("enter name: ");
    scanf_s("%15s", name[i], 16);
    if (strcmp(name[i], "-1") == 0)
        break; 
    printf("enter hourly rate: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &hourlyRate[i]);
    if (hourlyRate[i] == -1)
        break;
    printf("enter hours worked: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &hoursWorked[i]);
    if (hoursWorked[i] == -1)
        break;

    counter++;
}

return counter;
}

void main()
{
const float OVERTIMEHOURS = 40.0f;
const float OVERTIMERATE = 1.5f;
const float TAX = 0.20f;
char name[5][16] = { "", "", "", "", "" };
float hourlyRate[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float hoursWorked[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float amountPaid[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float basePay[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float overPay[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float taxPaid[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float netPay[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float overTime[5] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
float totalPaid = 0.0f;

int counter = 0;


counter = askUser(name[5][16], &hourlyRate[5], &hoursWorked[5]);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduce your bug

Comment: At this stage in your programming career, you should assume that if the compiler generates a warning, you've got a bug in your code.  Even a few years down the road, that'll still be the case far more often than not (99 times out of 100).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going wrong here

```
counter = askUser(name[5][16], &hourlyRate[5], &hoursWorked[5]);
```

Your function `askuser` require first argument of type `char[][]` but you are passing argument of type `char` and this goes true for all the passed arguments

so the corrected call to `askuser()` should be

```
counter = askUser(name, hourlyRate, hoursWorked);
```

The same error is repeated twice more in main
Please take a look at compiler warnings before running the code.